# Distributions similar to the family of stable distributions

Tags: probability, distributions

Are there any other distributions with similar properties to the family of [stable distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distributions)? That is, $\alpha$-stable, normal tempered stable, classical tempered stable, etc. etc. where the distribution could exhibit the following properties: Heavy tailed, leptokurtotic, symmetric or asymmetric but can still retain some of the Gaussian properties?

For instance setting $\alpha = 2$ in any of the stable distributions will result in a normal distribution with no leptokurtotic or heavy tailed properties.

I know of the [generalized hyperbolic distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalised_hyperbolic_distribution) family which is similar in features and also,  for a few special cases when the degrees of freedom are very high decays to the gaussian.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question. Defining (nonstandard) initialisms like NTS and CTS would help. What are "some of the Gaussian properties" you are hoping to retain?

Comment: @cardinal i removed the abbreviations for you, i'll update the question to make it more clear